# Relacionamento entre tabelas no SELECT - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, select, servidor, relacionamento

Estou com uma duvida de como adicionar um relacionamento entre tabelas.

Exemplo:
Estou usando esse comando para pegar os dados. Porém ele me retorna com os ID's das outras tabelas. Gostaria que fosse retornado os nomes relacionados aos ids.

```
SELECT * FROM BASE_MARCACAO
WHERE MA_DATA='2019-02-25 00:00:00.000' AND MA_CLINICA='1' and MA_PROFISSIONAL='6771' and MA_CLIENTE_CONVENIO IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: tem de detalhar mais a sua questão, está muito vaga.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode resolver isto por meio de um `INNER JOIN`.

Segue exemplo:

```
SELECT bm.MA_DATA as data, 
       bm.MA_CLINICA as clinica, 
       bm.MA_PROFISSIONAL as profissional, 
       ot.NOME as nomeOutraTabela
FROM BASE_MARCACAO bm
INNER JOIN OUTRA_TABELA ot
ON bm.id = ot.id
WHERE bm.MA_DATA='2019-02-25 00:00:00.000' AND bm.MA_CLINICA='1' and bm.MA_PROFISSIONAL='6771' and bm.MA_CLIENTE_CONVENIO IS NOT NULL
```

Só fazendo uma observação para melhor entendimento da resposta: `OUTRA_TABELA` seria a tabela na qual os nomes referentes aos respectivos ids estariam.

Outra coisa, `bm` e `ot` são alias das suas respectivas tabelas,já `clinica, data, profissional e nomeOutraTabela` são alias das colunas de cada tabela. É boa pratica usar sempre para que fique mais legível o código.